# How to transform, translate in this situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to move `div.willshow` when var about clicked.
But I click that btn, only It gets class `active`.
And I click that btn again It lose class. And If I click one more time, every task not working.

CSS

```
div.willshow {
    width:calc(100% - 52px);
    height:100%;
    margin-left: 52px;
    z-index:100;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left:-100%;
    -ms-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

div.willshow.active {
    -ms-transform: translate(-100%, 0); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}
```

Javascript

```
var about = $('ul.about > li > span');
var willshow = $('div.willshow');

about.click(function(){
    willshow.addClass('active');
    about.html('close');

    about.click(function(){
        willshow.removeClass('active');
        about.html('about');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single click event,toggle the text using if in the html function:

```
about.on('click',function(){
    willshow.toggleClass('active');
    about.html(function(){
       if($(willshow).hasClass('active')) {
          return 'close';
       }
       return 'about';
    });

});
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/ztw7uxhy/1/

Comment: Good answer, only to write that could be improved by using [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) instead of an IIFE

Comment: sorry for checking lately. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I think your script will work better makeing something like this

```
var about = $('ul.about > li > span');
var willshow = $('div.willshow');
var active;

about.click(function(){
if (active!='yes'){
    willshow.addClass('active');
    about.html('close');
    active='yes';
else{
    willshow.removeClass('active');
    about.html('about');
    active='no';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `about` click handler you can use [jQuery#toggleclass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to set `willshow` class and then with the use of a [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) you can get the proper `about` class in a clean way:

```
var about = $('ul.about > li > span'),
    willshow = $('div.willshow');

about.click(function () {
    willshow.toggleClass('active');
    about.html(willshow.hasClass('active') ? 'close' : 'about');
});
```

Comment: if you copy at least make sure what you copy is right :) the hasclass need to be on the willshow variable, and what's with the $ in the variables ?

Comment: @madalinivascu was not copied by your answer.. and thanks, i have corrected my error. Good your answer and the demo.. You have my +1. Thanks

Comment: Corrected variable names... I normally to use `$` in variable names when the variable represents a jQuery object... I tend to get out of the OP.. I know it's my bad.. Thanks ;)

Comment: The solution to the question is to make a code refactor.. Both we are using [jQuery#toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).. That's why the answers are very similar ;)